# Need help solving an integral, and also checking my work on another problem.

Tags: calculus

I'm hoping you can help me with two questions I'm having trouble with.
The first is this:

Use an arc length integral to calculate the length of the path over the given interval.
    $$(\sin x- x \, \cos x, \cos x + x \, \sin x), \, 0 \leq x \leq 4$$

I got arc length integral by taking the derivative of the two points like so:
$$\frac{d}{dx} = (-\sin x, x \, \cos x)$$
Then the length is the integral over the interval (0,4)
so $$\int_{4}^{0} \sqrt{\sin x^2 + (x^2) \, \cos x^2} \, dx$$

My issue is I can't figure out how to do the integral.

My second problem is this:
Find the minimum speed of a particle with trajectory
$c(t)=((t^3)-6t, (t^2)+1)$ for $t \geq 0$

For this one, I got the velocity function by taking the derivative of the function above like so: $v(t)=((3t^2)-6, 2t)$
And I got the speed by getting the magnitude like so:
$$s(t) = \sqrt{(9t^4)-(36t^2)+36+(4t^2)}$$

And I got the minimum to be sqrt(2) but it's wrong and I don't know why.

Comment: For the arclength, it is a parametric curve, and it would be (much) better to Use $t$ than to use $x$. Differentiate the two expressions, square, and add. If it is done right it will greatly simplify.

Comment: For the second question, note that the derivative of the square of speed is $36t^3-64t$. If we set this equal to $0$, there are three roots.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  I got 3 roots. $t=0$ and $t=+/- (4/3)$

Comment: @imranfat: Thanks, and within the editing window!

Comment: This impies by the way that there are 2 values for t where the speed is at a minimum. For $t=0$ the particle enjoys momentarily a max speed